# Use a Gateway as a Router only?

Tags: router, wireless-router, modem, gateway

I just switched from Verizon FiOS to Comcast internet. I still have my Verizon Gateway (modem + router combo) - looks like this:

[image: Verizon Gateway (modem + router combo)]

I know it's not compatible with Comcast as a gateway device, but if I get a Comcast-compatible modem, can I use the Verizon Gateway as a router and hook the Comcast-compatible modem into it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? There's probably a way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to get a modem and router (for wifi) - so basically I wanted to see if I could just get a modem, and save money on a router by using the Verizon device.

Comment: Try and hook any modem to it and see if it will work. Comcast compatible is irrelevant. And it's possible it will work. You can get lucky. I've done something like that - either that or as a test, plugging the modem into a LAN port rather than the WAN port that was there. In your case you don't have a WAN port but you could still try it in a LAN port see if it works  It "shouldn't" but don't rule it out. I think sometimes it might work. though one probably shouldn't use a setup that is dodgy, defying nature!

Comment: i've heard of modem/routers have a function to disable the router aspect but not the modem aspect. If you can get your hands on the manual it might give you a clue. Also, why not just ask comcast to provide a modem/router with their services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. In order to use it as a router the device has to have an "incoming" ethernet port. This is where you would plug the Ethernet cable from the Comcast modem and that interface would be assigned the public IP.

Since there is no photo of the back I am going to use my own device that looks similar and it has no ethernet port - it is because the modem and router are connected internally thus there is no need for it.

Comment: I may have had something like that work once, you can always try it. It might've been with a Router but not using the modem ethernet port (that should be similar to taking a modem/router device, without WAN port, and plugging the modem into a LAN port).  But of course, one shouldn't buy a device expecting it to work.

Comment: Those FiOS routers (made by Actiontec) *do*  have an Ethernet WAN port on the back.  They actually don't contain a modem at all:  FiOS uses a separate device called an ONT (optical network terminal), which provides both Ethernet and coaxial ([MoCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_over_Coax_Alliance)) interfaces for connecting a router.  The Verizon technicians typically use the coaxial since most homes are wired for it, but the router supports both, and either will work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, yes you can, as long as there is an Ethernet IN port which it SHOULD definitely have, you most certainly can. I know this because I DO THIS with my modem/router combo, there is no COAX hooked up to it. I have a modem already AND a wireless router, I just needed one to extend my range so what I did was grabbed my old modem/router combo with the same question in mind, ran an Ethernet from my current wireless routers OUT to my modem/router combos IN (it has four ports all act as an IN AND an OUT) and to my surprise I had a signal. Then I proceeded to enter the password and logged in. After that just to confirm I browsed the web and even downloaded an app on my phone, and it worked perfectly fine. Although these routers tend to be on the low end side it got the job done, and now I have two access points in my house. You don't like to use range extenders or repeaters because it takes away from your current bandwidth/strength.

To answer your question if it has an IN or not, you can tell simply by looking to see if it has a yellow ring or LED light, if so, that it is an IN and if green or blank it's an OUT. Mine has both a yellow and a green LED on each one and the light will blink according to which way it's hooked up, in this case "in", so it flashes yellow.